# Did August Walker fake this injury?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

There's a scene in Mission Impossible: Fallout, where Ethan Hunt and August Walker skydive out of a plane. Suddenly they fly through a thunder cloud and August Walker apparently gets hit by lightning and passes out, forcing Ethan to save him by using his own oxygen tank

Though we later find out that...

> ...August Walker is really John Lark, the *bad guy*!

Therefore, did Walker really get that injury, or did he fake it? If yes, why would he fake it? And if he didn't fake it, what was the point of that part of the film anyway?

Comment: Opinion: no he didn't fake it simply because there would be no point for him to fake it. The point of that part of the movie was for a suspenseful action scene. Also I suppose to add to his character building as being a reckless wild card who's actions kept putting the mission in jeopardy.

Answer (score 5):

Totally Agree with Sanpaco's comment - that scene was there for increasing tension of action as well August dived there recklessly and was struct by lightning.

Additionally, I don't think August really knows that he was struck by lightning and passed out, nor that Hunt actually saved him by providing his oxygen tank. You can see that in the dialog after they land on the roof: August suggests to Ethan that his tank is leaking the same way Ethan told August before jump.

So simply, if you don't know about it, how can you fake it?

Comment: *What* do you agree with? Feel free to add the essential parts of the comment you agree with into the answer. Comments are ephemeral and it's better to have self-contained answers.

Comment: Again, please don't put it into the comments but the actual question.

Comment: though it was weird that he woke up before landing and landed smoothly like nothing happened lol

Comment: No, It's not weird. The thing which got struck by lightning was his **Oxygen tank**. He faced a shock & also lost his Oxygen supply and passed out. When he got oxygen back from another tank, he woke up in the next few seconds.